# Вывести строку обратную данной

Tags: строки, c++

Хочу ввести строку и вывести ее наоборот. На вывод не поступает абсолютно ничего.
п.с.: не нужно предлагать мне подключить библиотеку строк.

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

char rev_str(char *s1);

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
/*SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);*/

char s1_pr[100];
cout << "Напишите любую строку: ";
cin >> s1_pr;
cout << "Строка наоборот: " << rev_str(s1_pr);

cin >> s1_pr;
return 0;
}

char rev_str(char *s1) {
int l = strlen(s1);
char *res = new char [l];
for(int a = l, b = 0; a >= 0; a--, b++) {
    res[b] = s1[a];
}
return *res;
}
```

Comment: В C++ никаких «библиотек строк» не нужно. Пользуйтесь `std::string`, как и полагается в C++, а не C-шным `char*`.

Если это только не учебное задание (но тогда уж сами, а то никогда не научитесь.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

char возвращаете, а нужно char*. А в этот байт, который вернули, вы как раз завершающий 0 записали.

UPD:

```
char* rev_str(char *s1) {
    int l = strlen(s1);
    char *res = new char [l];
    for(int a = l-1, b = 0; a >= 0; a--, b++) {
        res[b] = s1[a];
    }
    return res;
}
```

а еще:

```
char s1_pr[100];
cout << "Напишите любую строку: ";
cin.getline( s1_pr, 100 );
```

Comment: Теперь что бы я не вводил, программа возвращает заглавную "Н".

Comment: а как вывести все символы?

Comment: Так и сделал. Все равно при любом вводе возвращает "Н".

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: Аа, все, благодарю!

Comment: деструктор для `res` после вывода не забудьте позвать. Только не в самой функции `rev_str` :).

Answer (score 4):

Так как вы вопрос обозначили тегом "C++", то приведу только два C++-шных способа, которые, конечно же, базируются на классе String:

```
string line = "543210";

// 1 си-подобный( без "всяких там" STL )
float length = line.size()-1;
for(int i=0;i<length/2;i++)
{
    char foo = line[i];
    line[i] = line[length-i];
    line[length-i] = foo;
    }
cout<<line<<endl;

// 2 ( используя любимый STL )
reverse(line.begin(),line.end());
cout<<line<<endl;
```

Comment: Гордитесь собой до конца жизни. Конечно, так будет проще. А если я не хочу проще? Да, я хочу сделать все через заднее месте, но зато я буду представлять, как примерно это реализовывается.

Comment: Да я, собственно, ничего такого даже не имел ввиду. По манере твоей речи и духу заданного вопроса все и так стало ясно. Я лишь высказал, возможно, горькую для кого-то правду..

Comment: @Цветухин Михаил: сложно будет в реальных задачах и без вашей помощи, а на простых не стоит искусственно усложнять себе жизнь.

Comment: @0xFFh для *си-подобный( без "всяких там" STL )* лучше как-нибудь так...

    char *c = line;
    char *d = line + strlen(line) - 1;
    while (c < d) {
        char t = *c;
        *c++ = *d;
        *d-- = t;
    }

Comment: @0xFFh Вы бы поаккуратнее хелловорлдами-то кидались. Можно чуток уточнить задачу: строка на русском языке, кодировка utf8...

Comment: @alexlz, ахаха, хотел что-то подобное написать. Просто смешать такие люди, которые пишут "зачем такие люди в программировании", но при этом думают что string - не часть stl.
 
@0xFFh,Что это вообще за анализ такой о том, кто и где должен быть. Каждый с чего-то начинает и все мы такими были и если кто-то ещё таким остался, то у него есть свои причины на это. Программирование - это не ракетное моделирование и каждый здоровый человек может ему обучится, если захочет и потратит достаточно времени, что впрочем и ракетного моделирования касается.

Comment: Так вот не нужно возносить себя как какого-то гения или ещё чего, после изучения определенного дела, потому что в мире есть тысячи профессий и в каждой кто-то хорош. Но ещё больше людей, которые не тратят все время на изучения одной профессии, чтобы быть в ней хорошим, потому что в жизни есть ещё очень много других дел.
И вообще не понятно откуда в данном случае у вас появляется гордость за свои познания, если это всего лишь одна или парочка областей из бесчисленного множества. И примерная оценка им - 0.00001% от общего числа. Почти нету глупых людей, есть только те, кто хорош в чем-то своем.

Comment: >> но при этом думают что string - не часть stl.

здесь не все так просто. Настоящие программисты знают, что ответ зависит от того, что именно понимается под словом stl. Занимательное обсуждение на [RSDN](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/1453711.flat).

Ни `STL`, ни `Standard Template Library` в стандарте не упортребляется.

Comment: @KoVadim лень искать, но вроде Степанов свою библиотеку подарил для включения в стандарт. Т.е. вопрос о её присутствии в стандарте неотделим от вопроса "что есть STL?".

Comment: то, что stl входит в c++ standard library, не значит, std::string являются частью stl.

Comment: @Robert Pinkman

>Почти нету глупых людей, есть только те, кто хорош в чем-то своем

Еще как есть, и навалом, как ни прискорбно (не применительно к ТСу)

Comment: Ладно, как понимаю, мое высказывание относительно "людей в программировании" оказалось ни к месту. @Robert Pinkman, о себе я не сказал ни слова в ответе, заметьте. Следовательно, никакой гордости нет. Да и вообще, честно говоря, я, скорее, ощущаю себя "туповатым" :)